# get file with dynamic download link from page

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, python-requests

I need to get all files for the last 2 years regarding market data, this data is in daily xls files in separate URLs.For example: http://www.atsenergo.ru/nreport?rname=trade_zsp&rdate=20150914

The issue arises from the dynamic link that is tied to the file download, i.e:
http://www.atsenergo.ru/nreport?fid=1FA2D73D285FD4DCE05010AC47064410

Is there a way to crawl all the pages (easily done with the date field) and get the xls file for every link?

Looking at other questions I tried:

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.atsenergo.ru/nreport?rname=trade_zsp&rdate=20150914')
content_type = response.info().get('Content-Type')
print(content_type)
```

To try and get the 'application/octet-stream' type and find the link but I only get 'text/html;charset=UTF-8'

Comment: Please mention what have you tried so far? A code sample will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to loop through the dates, so you have to set a start date (2 years ago) and add day by day. 
For every day you request the webpage and parse it for the link to the xml file (should be easy when you search for an a-Tag ending with xsl). 
Then you have the url and you can download the xls for the given day.

The content type is not what you are looking for.